# Force request to a URL on a different domain

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make a request to a page on a different domain when a user clicks a link in order to keep the session alive on that domain. I don't care about the response data (except *maybe* the status code so I can make sure the page hasn't gone down). I tried issuing a request via `$.ajax` but the same-origin policy is disallowing it.

What's the best way to make request go through?

Should I write an iframe to my page? A script tag? Is there an option in `$.ajax` that will make it work?

**Edit:** I also need to know when the request gone through so that I can do some stuff afterwards (i.e., I'd like a callback).

---

Adding `dataType: 'jsonp'` sort of makes it work, except that I don't want it to execute whatever the site returns, which it seems to do. The page I'm requesting is a regular old HTML page, but it triggers some stuff on their server that keeps the session alive.

Comment: Hint: If you load the script that makes that request from that domain, it won't be affected by the same-origin policy.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp: Huh? I'm not sure what you're trying to say there. What script?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you're trying to do.. but what I understand is that you have two domains, a.com and b.com. On a.com you want to make requests to b.com. So when you load the page under a.com, have a <script> tag whose src points to b.com and loads a JS file from there. Then, from that JS file you are free to make requests back to b.com however you are on a.com (because the script loaded from b.com). Of course, this only works if you have control over both domains.

Comment: `b.com` is not under my control, and there aren't any JS files on `b.com` I'm interested in.

Comment: I meant that YOU put a file there, but if you don't control the 2nd domain (b.com), it's out of question.

Comment: You may still make (pre-flighted) requests to b.com, but that also requires control of that domain since b.com must return an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header that allows your script on a.com to access resources on b.com. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

Comment: @MarcellFülöp: Well I know this is possible. `jsonp` somehow gets around the same-origin policy, and otherwise iframes and script tags should work. Perhaps even an image tag. Edit: Ah..`jsonp` just creates a script tag. Wasn't sure how it worked.

Comment: Why not request a resource on b.com that doesn't exist?  You'll get the 404 and ignore it, but it should keep the session alive.

Comment: @SteveH. I don't think so. They want you to click a specific link on their page to refresh the session. It's very stupid. You're essentially only allowed to use the site for 30 minutes at a time, then you have to click a link and go for another 30. Government website.

Answer (score 1):

You can send request using Image "class":

```
var img = new Image();
img.onerror = img.onload = function() { console.log('Sended') }
img.src = "http://google.com?hey=google&rnd=" + Math.random() // random is used to prevent caching
```

But unless response isn't a picture, you'll not get any information about resource availability.

Also, I'm not sure if this solution is cross-browser. It seems to work in recent Opera and Chrome, but I haven't tested it in any other browser.

BTW, this image approach seems to be the only one that is safe. If you include scripts or load iframes, they could do something evil with your page, while simple image stays harmless.

Comment: I thought the same-origin policy also protects me from them manipulating/accessing my DOM from within their iframe?

Comment: Sure! But many sites dislike being jailed in frames (because of so called "click-jacking"; try google.com, for exmaple) :-) As far as I know, it is still possible to do some restricted manipulations like changing page's location. Again, it maybe browser-dependent.

Comment: There is a story about it: one well-known russian social network decided to punish some site (de-capther) and embeded hidden 1px iframe on all pages. It caused ddos to that site. But that guys were smart enough: they set script that changes parent's location (code can be found here: http://habrahabr.ru/post/142836/#comment_4783210) to some porno-site. Some users were redirected to that page, some weren't.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
$('#myelement').on('click',function() {
    $('<iframe>', {src:'http://otherdomain.com/page'}).hide().load(function() {
        $(this).remove(); //clean up the DOM
        // do stuff
    }).appendTo('body');
});
```